# Reasoning About Recursive Functions

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion

I'm working through the fourth edition of Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne and am stumped on exercise 1.1.27 which asks:

> Estimate the number of recursive calls that would be used by the code
>
> ```
> public static double binomial(int N, int k, double p)
> {
>   if ((N == 0) || (k < 0)) return 1.0;
>   return (1.0 - p)*binomial(N-1, k, p) + p*binomial(N-1, k-1, p);
> }
> ```
>
> to compute binomial(100, 50).

Although I'd like like help answering this question, I'd also like to get better at understanding and reasoning about questions of this nature in general and so any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the initial value of `p`, assumed `0`?

Comment: You should read what some of the old mathematicians and scientists did. They used to record _pages and pages_ of raw calculations that they did by hand. Some people would write the first 500 members of a sequence to get an idea of the properties of some sequence with the goal that that would help them prove some property. The same applies here... did you try plugging in some values and writing out the number of recursive calls by hand? Nowadays you could modify the code slightly and have a computer tell you; but there's no real harm in doing it on paper

Comment: @mbratch The exercise in its entirety is in my question but I don't think it matters anyway as it has no effect on the recursive properties of the function

Comment: @roliu Thanks. I'm doing that now in a diagram editor (I'm making a tree structure) but I'm really looking for help at getting better at reasoning about these kinds of things.

Comment: Once you have a hypothesis about how fast it grows, you can start going about proving it. Are you saying you have trouble proving your claim to be true? It will _always_ be necessary to do some calculations by hand in math... the only thing experience gives you is the ability to make good guesses based on previous results you've proved/understood. Fyi, I believe it's possible to prove the closed form for this recursive equation directly using generating functions. But that's a lot of calculation and the "guess + induction" method is more common. In this case they just want an estimate

Comment: @roliu While I'm interested in it, my mathematics isn't very good. I don't even know what "closed form" means. I was hoping for pointers in where to direct my interest in studying algorithms/computer science and the corresponding mathematics.

Comment: It depends how much math you want to do honestly. Most algorithms books will teach you the math you need to know for a reasonably formal proof (often in the appendix). Otherwise you can search for a general book in discrete mathematics. I think a lot of good lists have been compiled on the stackexchange sites themselves: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/what-is-the-best-book-for-studying-discrete-mathematics. I actually recall a much longer list somewhere... I remember really wanting to read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It.

Comment: The perplexing thing is that this problem is at a point in the book before recursion has been covered in any depth and before any mathematics has been taught.

Comment: Modulo a small difference at the base cases, the recursion is the same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619187/what-is-the-big-o-complexity-of-this-naive-code-to-compute-combinations).

Comment: @DanielFischer Nice work! I'm sad I couldn't remember the result (since I remember proving it!) but binomial coefficients seem to grow at `O(2^n/sqrt(n))` (so I think the `min` will always win out?) Pretty cool

@SimonMorgan They just want an estimate. If you wrote down the number of calls for like... `N = 0... 6` and `k = 0...3` and gave a guess, that's good enough (I think at least?). I would've put down a guess of `2^100` or something like that.

Comment: @roliu Yes, `binom(n, n/2)` is (ignoring a constant factor involving `sqrt(pi)`), asymptotically `2^n/sqrt(n)`. The number of recursive calls for `binom(n,(n-1)/2)` is, for odd `n`, then `2^n` give or take one or two [not sure how the base case choice here changes the number]. It's a bit more complicated for general `binom(n,k)`, but Stirling should help. Couldn't be bothered to fight with the details there, though, so I gave a coarse estimate for small `k`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry I meant `binom(n,k)` is `O(binom(n,n/2))` so the `min` you had you should be a tighter upper bound always

Comment: @roliu For small `k` (relative to `n`, but large enough in absolute numbers), the `min` I gave is not tight, you can bound it with something smaller than `(k+1)*binom(n,k)`. Not sure whether `sqrt(k+1)*binom(n,k)` would do or even something smaller. At which point I notice, as written, it's wrong, since I implicitly assumed `k < n/2` for the `min`. (Fixed now.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This algorithm traverses Pascal's triangle.

You can arrange the triangle traversal as a rectangle N * K. If the algorithm visits every cell only once, then total is 100 * 50 = 5000.

Here is an example:

[image: Pascal's Triangle with rectangle]

In this example N=6 and K=4.

However, the problem is that the algorithm does not remember what cells it already visited so it is redundantly visiting cells. Each call DOUBLES the number of calls (oops, bad).

So it goes 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + ...

The sum of powers of 2 is 2^(n+1)-1, so it would be 2^101 - 1 = 2535301200456458802993406410751

That is a big number. Do not run this program.

(Note that the number is only approximate because some calls do not double if K<0, so it may the above number divided by 2 or so).

Comment: I think it grows much faster than Pascal's because there are many redundant recursive calls. For instance (3,2) results in 12 calls.

Comment: That is true, it is not memoized so it redundantly visits cells.

Answer (score 1):

You'll see the pattern right away if you start with concrete examples. For N=0, obviously it's 0. For N=1, it's 2 recursive calls (because each call yields two recursive call at the directly inferior level, i.e. for N-1.

For N=2, then it's 2*2 = 4

For N=3, then it's 2*2*2 (i.e. 2^3)

For N=4, then it's 2^4

I'm assuming you see the pattern.

Comment: What about the cases where `k` is less than `N`?

Comment: (k < 0) this condition come first. so 2^50.